# in app purchase test user

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have implemented the in app purchase model in my app and i have tested the features using a test user as apple suggested and the 'sandbox url' but when i try to use my itunes store account (not the test user) to purchase the features with the 'buy url' i get an error saying that "this user is not a test user" .

I have a question if anyone could help me...What will happen when the app is ready for sale will the itunes store users be able to download the in app purchase features or they will get this message too?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual iTunes store account will not work in the test sandbox.

Since the test user account does work, the in-app purchases in the final app should work fine once users download it. I believe Apple will test the in-app purchases when reviewing your app also.

Comment: thanks for telling me joet3ch. I was really anxious about this question!